# Generating a file in the background based on user request

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, file

I have a C# web application (MVC1, .NET 3.5) with a function to generate reports. I was wondering if anyone has suggestions for how to implement the following scenario:

1. Logged in user clicks on the report button and goes on to browse other parts of the website OR simply logs off
2. Once the report is finished generating, it is e-mailed to the user

Main question being - how can I start a separate thread on the server that will accomplish this? If multithreading is not the way to go, please feel free to make other suggestions. Typical time to generate a report can be upwards of 10 minutes. Also, this functionality will rarely be used by more than one user at a time so I am imagining something along the route of "queueing up" a function and letting it execute in the background.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Baz1nga Correct... for 10minute work maybe need only one thread that do a query work...., or something like Erik suggest

Answer (score 4):

I suggest creating a Windows Service that polls the database for reports to generate, generates them and emails them.  The specifics of the report are entered by the user on the website and the website simply stores that information in a database.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Erik. This functionality will be rarely used by more than one user so the Windows Service approach may be an overkill. Is there a simpler way to just "queue up" a function in the background and let it run?

Comment: I use windows services for these kinds of tasks all the time.  I recommend this approach anyway because of a few reasons; threading in IIS is not straight forward, there are plenty of issues like an AppPool restarting or what if you want to change the report, that shouldn't require redeployment of a website.  Besides Windows Services in C# are pretty straight forward.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at utilizing [Microsoft Windows HPC Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/hpc/en/us/default.aspx).. It fits your use case perfectly or you can stick to the routine and write a windows service that does this for you. But if you can afford it I would recommend jumping on the HPC bandwagon..

You can start reading about it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/hpc/en/us/product/cluster-computing.aspx)

Comment: Thats really hitting a nail with a $1k per processor sledgehammer.  A simple scheduled task or background task should suffice.

Comment: that totally depends on the use case and the reach of his application.. Smtimes a workman needs to pick up $1k sledgehammer if he needs to drill 1000 nails in an hour.. I dont see a reason for the downvote, a comment should address your concern..